# ImageMagick convert: unable to load module

Tags: openserver, imagemagick

Вообщем в одном проекте пытался конвертировал картинки через консоль, но ничего не происходила, после я попытался сделать это ручками и получил такую ошибку:

```
$ convert d:/OpenServer/domains/iBrush/teleportAdmin/web/uploads/temp_files/1627471860_1_photo_row_gTm_TWQX5 l5eTZP2xYcsyCrzn0fIj60X.jpg -auto-orient -quality 90 d:/OpenServer/domains/iBrush/teleportAdmin/web/uploads/temp_files/1627471860_2_photo_row_gTm_TWQX5l5eTZP2xYcsyCrzn0fIj60X.jpg
convert: unable to load module 'd:\openserver\modules\imagemagick\modules\coders\IM_MOD_RL_JPEG_.dll': Не найдена указанная процедура.
@ error/module.c/OpenModule/1275.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `JPEG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/509.
convert: no images defined `d:/OpenServer/domains/iBrush/teleportAdmin/web/uploads/temp_files/1627471860_2_photo_row_gTm_TWQX5l5eTZP2xYcsyCrzn0fIj60X.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3275.
```

Ну вообщем такая ошибка, хотя в папке она есть, и да как видите я использую openserver, imagemagick в нём включён.

Вообщем нужна ваша помощь, как починить эту вещь?

Comment: и вот эта dll - d:\openserver\modules\imagemagick\modules\coders\IM_MOD_RL_JPEG_.dll  лежит там где нужно и имеет не нулевой размер?

Comment: @KoVadim  Да там где нужно и весит 52кб